# Can I save post meta programatically without setting metaboxes?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I want to know if is it required to have metaboxes set to save post meta into a custom post type.

I have a couple of pages where I save metadata into a post programatically, using `add_post_meta`, but I wanted to know if I can save data that is not set using `add_meta_box`.

Is it possible? What kind of considerations I should have about this?

Comment: You should always use `update_post_meta()`  function because if the term doesn't exict it will make a call to the `add_post_meta()` automatically. The same goes for `update_user_meta()`.Example if you  want to ass the meta "City" but you don't have it in the db you simply make a `update_post_meta($city)` and in $city you need the post_id and the new value. For more information refer to : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @knif3r. Anyway, I wanted to know that, if no metaboxes are defined in my CPT, any meta data I save using `update_user_meta()` will be saved in the database or not.

Comment: Yes it will be saved :)

Comment: Well, I did a couple of tests and you're right, the data is saved. Could you please write all this as an answer so I can mark it as the right answer? Thank you for your help, you're awesome. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `update_post_meta()` function because if the term doesn't exist it will make a call to the `add_post_meta()` automatically.

The same goes for `update_user_meta()`.

Example if you want to add the meta "City" but you don't have it in the db you simply make a `update_post_meta($city)` and in `$city` you need the `post_id` and the `new value for city`. 
Like that :

```
$city = array(
'post_id' => $post_id,
'city' => 'Melbourne'
);
```

For more information refer to : codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta